# Android: unifying byte[] and int[] usage?

Tags: java, android, arrays

So I have 2 lines of my code that will not play nice together, they are as follows:

```
is.readFully(px_data, 0, BMP_SIZE);
bmp.setPixels(px_data, 0, DIMENSION, 0, 0, DIMENSION, DIMENSION);
```

where "is" is an InputStream and "bmp" is a Bitmap.  px_data is of type byte[].  Therefore I have a compile error on the second line.  Problem is "readFully()" needs this to be of type byte[], but "setPixels()" requires it to be of type int[].  Any way to make them play nicely?  They don't seem to have alternate function prototypes allowing the usage of int[] in readFully() or vice versa.

I know I can make a second array of type int[] and copy it into the int[] with bitshifts, but this is happening in a time sensitive piece of code and I'd like to avoid iterating over all the data to do that.

The data read in from InputStream is formatted in ARGB 8888 format.

This is kind of annoying because the documentation clearly illustrates that the for sexPixels(), a 32 bit ARGB888 px value is used, which is exactly what I have, but Java just won't allow me to cast the type, so I don't know how to get around this without doing a deep copy of the buffer.  Anybody know a way to resolve this?

I'd ideally like to do:

```
int[] int_arr = px_data;
```

Though Java will have none of that.  Also, I don't think Java has unions so I can't just overlap their memory access.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, reread your question. You really want to read `int`s from the stream.

```
InputStream is = YOUR_INPUT_STREAM;
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
```

`DataInputStream` has a `readInt()` method. So you can allocate an array of `int`s to read to.

```
final int[] PIXELS = new int[DIMENSION * DIMENSION];

for(int i = 0; i < PIXELS.length; ++i){
  PIXELS[i] = dis.readInt();
}
```

Now you have an `int` array containing your pixel data and you can apply it to the `Bitmap`.

```
bitmap.setPixels(PIXELS, 0, DIMENSION, 0, 0, DIMENSION, DIMENSION);
```

Comment: as this is not a detailed answer, i think it's more of a comment, what do you think?

Comment: This is a time critical piece of code.  Creating new objects each iteration using BitmapFactory will add lots of overhead compared to using the same Bitmap each iteration.  They're guaranteed to be the same resolution, so not reusing the Bitmap is silly.  Never-the-less, I can try to get some metrics with it and see how bad the overhead is...though I'd really like to not do constant memory allocations, as this code executes in real time & it's on a slow device to begin with.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the reply, I considered that, but the problem is that's many many many calls to readInt(), and then I'm just wasting time in a time critical function.  Right now I'm calling readFully() with the size so it can copy it into the buffer in one shot, but then I have the type problem.

So I'm trying to minimize everything in this function because it's spending too much time there as-is, ideally 1 copy out of the stream into the bmp buffer, and no iteration to do so.

Never-the-less, I will try it and measure some metrics.

Comment: Ok, you've piqued my interest, what's the source of that `InputStream`?

Comment: Alex:  It's a socket to a server that I wrote.  The android app is the client.  The server will have no problem cranking data out, but the Android app has to post the data (to a canvas) as quickly as possible (real time, ideally, ~20fps+).

I did some metrics the multiple calls to readInt() did hurt it.  My naive solution (read all bytes from buffer, update canvas pixel by pixel) took 1.998 sec, which is way too slow.  readInt() loop you suggested takes 2.644, which is worse.  Best perf was found with a double copy (InputStream to ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer to Bitmap, Bitmap to Canvas 0.475 sec.